# Get an array of selected elements and its children

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have a php array of arrays returned by an external system in the following format

```
$elements = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Element 1',
        'parent_id' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Element 2',
        'parent_id' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Element 3',
        'parent_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Element 4',
        'parent_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Element 5',
        'parent_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'name' => 'Element 6',
        'parent_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'name' => 'Element 7',
        'parent_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'Element 8',
        'parent_id' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 9,
        'name' => 'Element 9',
        'parent_id' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Element 10',
        'parent_id' => 3
    ]
];
```

If it helps, this structure, "translated" to a tree would look like this:

- Element 1

  - Element 3

    - Element 8
    - Element 9
    - Element 10
  - Element 4
  - Element 5
- Element 2

  - Element 6
  - Element 7

What I need to do now is: for a given list of ids, return all the elements with the provided ids and its children (no matter how many levels). For example, if I receive an array with `[2, 3]` the output should be `[2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

I've created a function to generate a tree structure based on the array:

```
    public function createTree($parent = 0)
    {
        // This returns all the direct children of $parent
        $elements = filterByParent($parent); 
        $categories = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $categories[$i] = $element;
            $categories[$i]['children'] = createTree($element['id']);
            $i++;
        }

        return $categories;
    }
```

But I don't know how to proceed now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the methods as it's quite easy to create a list from a single recursive method.  This also passes in the `$elements` so that it can be tested easily.

The method can take either an ID or an array of ID's, if it's a single ID then it makes it an array so that it can `foreach()`  over the list.  Then it just checks it against each element and adds this into the working list.  Then calls the same method to find further sub items.

```
function dependants ( $ids, $elements )  {
    if ( !is_array($ids) )   {
        $ids = [$ids];
    }
    $deps = $ids;
    foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
        foreach ( $elements as $element )   {
            if ( $element['parent_id'] == $id ) {
                $deps = array_merge($deps, dependants($element['id'], $elements));
            }
        }
    }
    return $deps;
}
print_r(dependants([2,3], $elements ));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 10
)
```

Comment: That's amazing, thanks very much! I tried to add an if statement to also include 2 and 3 in the result list (the parameters provided), but it's duplicating elements. Is there any way to include them? If not, I guess I can just get the dependants and array_merge with the parameters

Comment: I've moved where the ID is added, so it's added at the start instead of in the middle.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was overcomplicating the issue. It looks so simple and so elegant when compared to my code.